# SonarQube 6.2 multi-language javascript and c#

Tags: javascript, c#, sonarqube

I am trying to get SonarQube to analyse and show code coverage for my project that has both C# code and pure javascript code. But I am unable to get any definitive pointers on how to achieve that. I tried using the multi module approach but in that the JavaScript coverage overwrites the c# one. Can anyone share a good example of successfully using C# and JS code coverage in the same project? The SonarQube documentation does not address this use case effectively.

Comment: I've had success using VS Test and `karma-coverage` in an angularJS/.NET application. What tools are you using to generate the reports and how are you submitting them to SonarQube for processing?

Comment: .Net coverage report is an XML using Opencover and Javascript using istanbul (LCOV format)

Comment: what do you mean by "the JavaScript coverage overwrites the c# one"? Is it 0 coverage for every C# file? Could you also show your project SQ config?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue! Have you found a solution for the issue? I want to set up a TFS build definition in which I want to analyse a JS App and a .NET Solution (C#) at once. But my current result is like yours - the last one overwrites the first one's results.